# Bibtex fails without citations... (test for citations? or invisible dummy cite)

Tags: bibtex, automation, makefile

I have a LaTeX folder where I use the same makefile and preamble for building either a part of the report or the entire report.  This is achieved by a hack in the makefile where I substitute the file I want to compile into the preamble (this part works fairly well).

But, whenever I build a document without citations, BibTeX fails, and LaTeX writes a warning saying `Empty 'thebibliography' environment on input line 5.`.

I can avoid this problem by doing a `\nocite{DummyCite}` and having an entry for dummy cite in my .bib file.  However, that's a rather nasty hack, and looks ugly when I have citations.

Is there any way I can figure out if there are citations?
Can I do an `\ifthenelse` against the citation counter?  How do I find out what the name of the citation counter is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `<file>.aux` does't have any `\citation{..}` line, then you have no `\cite{..}` in your document. In this case you should delete an existing `<file>.bbl`. Then LaTeX gives only a warning about a non existing file, which is not of interest for the LaTeX run.

Comment: Thanks
`if grep "\\citation" ./bin/$(*F).aux > /dev/null; then   if bibtex -terse ./bin/$(*F).aux; then     echo "bibtex:  OK"; else echo "bibtex:  Failed";   fi; fi`
Pretty much did the trick... Now I only run bibtex if there was any citations...